# pop index out of range error in Python when modifying a copy of lists and dictionaries while iterating through the original dictionary

Tags: python

I have two Python lists. One list, called `area = [1500, 500, 1500, 2000, 2500, 2000]`, stores the areas of homes. Another list, called `price = [30000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 45000]`, stores the corresponding prices of these homes. I created a dictionary called `priceDict`, whose keys are the unique areas of homes and whose values are lists of the prices of homes of the same area. I created another dictionary, called `priceIndexDict`, whose keys are the unique areas of homes and whose values are lists of indices of the prices of homes of the same area as shown in the `price` list.
I wrote the following Python code to create the two dictionaries.

```
area = [1200, 1200, 1200, 2000]
price = [15000, 11000, 17000, 25000]

priceDict = {}
priceIndexDict = {}
zipList = list(zip(area, price))
zipListIndex = 0

for k, v in zipList:
    priceDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    priceIndexDict.setdefault(k, []).append(zipListIndex)
zipListIndex += 1

print(priceDict)
print(priceIndexDict)
```

After I correctly got the `priceDict = {1200: [15000, 11000, 17000], 2000: [25000]}` and `priceIndexDict = {1200: [0, 1, 2], 2000: [3]}`, I would then like to create the new list `newPrice` and the new dictionary `newPriceDict` with the same contents as `price` and `priceDict` but with outliers of house prices for homes of the same size removed, as well as the new list `newArea` with the same content as ```area`` but with the corresponding areas for the house price outliers removed.

The following steps were used to determine the outliers:

- Select the home to test.
- Create a list of prices of other homes of the same size. It will be called compList in the examples.
- If there are no other homes of the same size, the house being tested is not an outlier.
- Otherwise:

  - Calculate the mean price, P[m], and the standard deviation, σ, for the homes compList.
  - If |price[i] - P[m]|> 3 * σ, the house is an outlier.

I wrote the following Python code. Note that function definitions for the `mean()`, `variance()` and `stdev()` functions are not shown here.

```
newArea = area.copy()
newPrice = price.copy()
newPriceDict = priceDict.copy()

for (houseArea, housePrice) in priceDict.items():
    if len(housePrice) == 1:
        continue
    for i in range(len(housePrice)):
        compList = housePrice.copy()
        compList.pop(i)
        if abs(housePrice[i] - mean(compList)) > 3 * stdev(compList):
            newArea.pop(priceIndexDict[houseArea][i])
            newPrice.pop(priceIndexDict[houseArea][i])
            newPriceDict[houseArea].pop(i)

print(newArea)
print(newPrice)
print(newPriceDict)
```

However, when I executed the code, the IDE displayed the following error:

```
line 44, in <module>
    compList.pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `newPriceDict[houseArea].pop(i)` modifies `housePrice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newPriceDict[houseArea].pop(i)` modifies `housePrice`. `newPriceDict` is a shallow copy of `priceDict`, so the values in the dictionary are the same as the values in `PriceDict`.

Use `copy.deepcopy()` to make a deep copy.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from statistics import mean, stdev

area = [1200, 1200, 1200, 2000]
price = [15000, 11000, 17000, 25000]

priceDict = {}
priceIndexDict = {}
zipList = list(zip(area, price))
zipListIndex = 0

for k, v in zipList:
    priceDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    priceIndexDict.setdefault(k, []).append(zipListIndex)
zipListIndex += 1

print(priceDict)
print(priceIndexDict)

newArea = area.copy()
newPrice = price.copy()
newPriceDict = deepcopy(priceDict)

for (houseArea, housePrice) in priceDict.items():
    if len(housePrice) == 1:
        continue
    for i in range(len(housePrice)):
        compList = housePrice.copy()
        compList.pop(i)
        if abs(housePrice[i] - mean(compList)) > 3 * stdev(compList):
            newArea.pop(priceIndexDict[houseArea][i])
            newPrice.pop(priceIndexDict[houseArea][i])
            newPriceDict[houseArea].pop(i)

print(newArea)
print(newPrice)
print(newPriceDict)
```